# AAD app registration not accepting the query string parameter

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory

I have registered the app in Azure AAD with reply urls. Enable id_token and auth token. If i give the exact url as the parameter it works fine. but if I add the query string as a parameter in reply url it is not working and throws error

> AADSTS50011: The reply url specified in the request does not match the
>   reply urls configured for the application: ''.

Below is my sample URL format generated by ADAL.js file.

> https://login.microsoftonline.com/.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authorize
>
> ?response_type=id_token &client_id=
>
> &redirect_uri=*?p1=123&p2=456*
>
> &state=62439108-d296-4a0d-91cc-4f6580656e83
>
> &client-request-id=1a5ad90a-26fc-4e60-bbcc-8d58bbbcc1f7
>
> &x-client-SKU=Js &x-client-Ver=1.0.13
>
> &nonce=a4a6215c-0706-4fbc-91a9-36e4cd3a262e

If i remove this *?p1=123&p2=456* query string from the redirect_url, it works fine. The other workaround i see is if i go to legacy app registration and add "*" at the end of the url it is working. But the new app registration does not allow "*" in the reply_url while registration.

Anyone else also faced the same issue and fixed without adding "*" in the reply_url registration? please let me know.

Comment: Not directly answering your question but you could pass your query string parameters (p1=123&p2=4560) in `state` query string parameter.

Comment: Hi Gauri. Actually the query string I'm not setting explicitly to reply_url From my web application ADAL.js automatically taking window.location.href and assigning to reply-url parameter. If i change manage to remove this parameter from url. then i'll be redirected to my home page of web app. I'll loose my application state where it was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an issue with ADAL.js (and MSAL.js) setting the redirect URI to the current URL by default.
You can get around it with an approach like this:

1. Set redirect URI as `window.location.origin +  "/aad-callback"` (or anything else)
2. When requiring login, store current URL in sessionStorage (or local storage or a cookie)
3. Trigger login redirect
4. When your app gets a callback to `/aad-callback`, handle the tokens from the URL fragment
5. Load the local redirect URL from sessionStorage
6. Redirect user there

I wrote an article related to this but for MSAL.js: https://joonasw.net/view/avoiding-wildcard-reply-urls-with-msal-js.
The concepts are the same for ADAL.js.

Comment: Thank you Juunas for your answer. It helps and i was having the similar thought. But actually The app created 2 years back works without wildcard symbol and app created this week with same configuration not working without wind card symbol in the reply_url registration. Only difference i see in the manifest is the old one has PublisherDomain as null, new app has Publisher domain with my tenant name (i.e. <abc>.onmicrosoft.com). now i see this property is read only and i could not edit it. Is it something supported by AAD earlier now stopped or am i missing something?

Comment: Certainly sounds like a change in AAD. Could be new ones have stricter rules.